# Rake Command Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake

Getting this error while running **RAKE** command :-

rake --trace

rake aborted!

```
There was an error while trying to load the gem 'coffee-rails'.
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block in require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/bundler-1.11.2/lib/bundler.rb:99:in `require'
/apps/apache/Sekhmet/user/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
/apps/apache/Sekhmet/user/Rakefile:5:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:637:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:165:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.1.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/rake-10.1.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
```

**Following is my Rake File:-**

require File.expand_path('../config/application', **FILE**)

MyAppName::Application.load_tasks

**Please Help!**

Comment: Re create your rails app or install bundler gem again. I suggest you to user better_errors gem to view errors better.

Comment: pradeepsapkota what can be the problem with existing bundle gem?

Comment: My be there is no rake file present in your app dir

Comment: It is there!
RAKEFILE is present along with Gemfile , Gemfile.lock etc..

Comment: Does running `bundle` in Application directory giving successful response ?

Comment: YogeshKhater
No,..had to re-install Bundle as pointed by pradeepsapkota and it worked!

Answer (score -1):

**Do this**

```
gem install coffee-rails
```

**Then restart server and run rake command**